# Вывести данные о сотрудниках возраст которого больше (60 для мужчин, 55 для женщин)

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("Введите кол-во сотрудников: ");
int PersonCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Person[] person = new Person[PersonCount];

for (int i = 0; i < PersonCount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Введите информацию о {i + 1} сотруднике: ");
    Console.Write("Фамилия: ");
    string FullName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Имя: ");
    string Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Отчество: ");
    string Patronymic = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Пол: ");
    string Orientation = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Должность: ");
    string Position = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Дата рождения: ");
    DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;

    person[i] = new(FullName, Name, Patronymic, Orientation, Position, Date);
}


for (int i = 0; i < PersonCount; i++)
{
    
}





struct Person
{
    public string FullName; // фамилия
    public string Name; // имя
    public string Patronymic; // отчество
    public string Orientation; // пол
    public string Position; // должность
    public DateTime Date; // дата рождения

    public Person(string FullName, string Name, string Patronymic, string Orientation, string Position, DateTime Date)
    {
        this.FullName = FullName;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Patronymic = Patronymic;
        this.Orientation = Orientation;
        this.Position = Position;
        this.Date = Date;
    }
}
```

Comment: А через массив не пробовал?

Comment: так в чем проблема ты не знаешь как вывести или что?

Comment: @ГорМанучарян, я не знаю как подсчитать возраст через DateTime и сделать вывод мужчин от 60лет, а женщин от 55лет

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new();
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
Console.WriteLine("Введи кол-во сотрудников");
int personCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= personCount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Введите информацию о {i} сотруднике: ");
    Console.Write("Фамилия: ");
    string FullName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Имя: ");
    string Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Отчество: ");
    string Patronymic = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Пол: ");
    string Orientation = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Должность: ");
    string Position = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Дата рождения: ");
    DateTime Date = new DateTime(2022 - rnd.Next(30, 80), 16, 16);

    persons.Add(new(FullName, Name, Patronymic, Orientation, Position, Date));
}
foreach (Person person in persons)
    if ((person.Orientation == "М" && person.Date > new DateTime(2022 - 60, 0, 0)) || (person.Orientation == "Ж" && person.Date > new DateTime(2022 - 55, 0, 0)))
        Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
```

```
public struct Person
{
    public Person(string FullName, string Name, string Patronymic, string Orientation, string Position, DateTime Date)
    {
        this.FullName = FullName;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Patronymic = Patronymic;
        this.Orientation = Orientation;
        this.Position = Position;
        this.Date = Date;
    }
    public string FullName { get; set; } // фамилия
    public string Name { get; set; } // имя
    public string Patronymic { get; set; } // отчество
    public string Orientation { get; set; } // пол
    public string Position { get; set; } // должность
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // дата рождения
    public override string ToString() => string.Join(",", FullName, Name, Patronymic, Orientation, Position, Date);
}
```